# Como ordenar argumentos de uma função python?

Tags: python, funções, argumento

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
def maluco(utrib,ucom,icms,desc,x,qtrib,vprod,fcp,ipi,dire,inf,nome=''):
    ...
```

E tentei chamá-la assim e de outros 30 jeitos:

```
qcx = maluco(utrib,ucom,icms,desc,x=y,qtrib,vprod,fcp,ipi,dire = 'nda',inf)
```

Porém sempre que chamo recebo um erro: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Qual a ordem para chamá-la e qual a diferença entre positional argument e keyword argument?

Comment: `def maluco(utrib,ucom,icms,desc,x=x,qtrib,vprod,fcp,ipi,dire=dire,inf,nome=''):`                                 Tentei declarar assim e resultou em: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque um argumento posicional não pode ser colocado depois de um com o valor definido no argumento, isso acontece tanto na definição da função quanto na chamada.
Tenho a seguinte função:

qcx = maluco(utrib,ucom,icms,desc,qtrib,vprod,fcp,ipi,inf,dire='nda',x=y)

Tenta fazer desse modo. :)

Argumento posicional(positional argument) é aquele que não tem valores definidos na chamada que é o caso de todos menos, dire e x.

Keyword é justamente o argumento que recebe um valor, ou seja, uma chave(key)

Comment: muito obrigado. me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine que temos a função:

```
def f(a, b):
    print("O argumento passado como parâmetro a é", a)
    print("O argumento passado como parâmetro b é", b)
```

Agora, chamamos a função da seguinte forma:

```
valor_1 = 2
valor_2 = 5
f(valor_1, valor_2)
# output:
# O argumento passado como parâmetro a é 2
# O argumento passado como parâmetro b é 5
```

Como o Python decide que a variável `valor_1` deve entrar como o parâmetro `a`, e a variável `valor_2` como `b`? Simplesmente por causa da **posição** que os argumentos são passados para a função. Neste caso, `valor_1` e `valor_2` são chamados de **argumentos posicionais** porque sua ordem define quem substituirá qual parâmetro dentro da função.

Mas também podemos chamar a função dessa forma:

```
valor_1 = 2
valor_2 = 5
f(b=valor_1, a=valor_2)
# output:
# O argumento passado como parâmetro a é 5
# O argumento passado como parâmetro b é 2
```

Neste caso, fomos explícitos ao indicar que `valor_1` deve ser entregue à função como o parâmetro `b`, não `a`. Para isso, usamos a **palavra-chave** do nome do parâmetro, como em `b=valor_1`. Dá-se a isso o nome de **argumentos de palavra-chave**. Note que, neste caso, não é necessário passar os argumentos na mesma ordem em que os parâmetros foram definidos na função.

Agora olhe este caso:

```
valor_1 = 2
valor_2 = 5
f(b=valor_1, valor_2)
# output:
# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

O erro aqui acontece porque **usamos argumentos de palavra-chave antes de argumentos posicionais**. Pela regra de argumentos posicionais, `valor_2` deveria ser associado ao parâmetro `b`, mas estamos explicitamente passando `valor_1` como `b`. Então, para evitar situações complicadas onde não se tem mais certeza que argumentos estão sendo passados para que parâmetros, logo de cara o **Python proíbe que argumentos de palavra-chave venham antes de argumentos posicionais** - é simplesmente uma regra da sintaxe da linguagem.

Então, para chamar sua função no seu caso, você pode passar todos os argumentos como argumentos posicionais (na ordem correta):

```
qcx = maluco(utrib, ucom, icms, desc, y, qtrib, vprod, fcp, ipi, 'nda', inf)
```

Ou então passar todos argumentos em qualquer ordem como argumentos de palavra-chave (decidi manter a ordem original por simplicidade, mas não é necessário):

```
qcx = maluco(utrib=utrib, ucom=ucom, icms=icms, desc=desc, x=y, qtrib=qtrib, vprod=vprod, fcp=fcp, ipi=ipi, dire='nda', inf=inf)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada, me sanou muitas dúvidas!